# EF savechanges exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have this exception when I try to update my entites..

*An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships.
The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception.
Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types.*

the code is described below

```
  public static void AggiungiNuovaBollaAiBinsInRiempimento(BollaEntrata bollaEntrata)
    {
        using (var model = new ModelLotti())
        {
            var repos = new RiempitoreRepository(model);

            var bolla = model.Bolle.Find(bollaEntrata.Id);

            if (bolla == null)
                throw new Exception("Impossibile Aggiunge una bolla inesistente ai bins in riempimento.");

            var riempitori = repos.GetAllRiempitori();


            for (int i = 0; i < riempitori.Length; i++)
            {
                if (riempitori[i].Bins != null)
                {
                    var riempimento = riempitori[i].Bins.GetRiempimentoCorrente();

                    if (riempimento != null && riempimento.Lotti.Select(x => x.LottoId).ToList().Contains(bollaEntrata.LottoId))
                    {
                        riempimento.AggiungiBolla(bolla);
                        model.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My entities are

```
    public  class BollaEntrata
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CodiceEAN { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime DataInizio { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime DataFine { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Lotto")]
    public long LottoId { get; set; }

    public Lotto Lotto { get; set; }

    public int NumeroBinsRovesciati { get; set; }

    public int NumeroPedaneRovesciate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Ingresso { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RigaRiempimento> RigheRiempimenti { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IngressoBolla> Ingressi { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DettagliBolla> DettagliBolla { get; set; }

 [Table("Riempimenti")]
public  class Riempimento
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long RiempimentoId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime DataInizio { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime DataFine { get; set; }

    public long BinsId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BinsId")]
    public BinsCalibrato BinsRiempito { get; set; }

    public Guid ProdottoGuid { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProdottoGuid")]
    public virtual Prodotto Prodotto { get; set; }

    public Guid PackId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PackId")]
    public virtual Confezione Confezione { get; set; }

    public short PercentualeRiempimento { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Lotto> Lotti { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RigaRiempimento> RigheRiempimenti { get; set; }

    public void AggiungiBolla(BollaEntrata bolla)
    {
        if (RigheRiempimenti.Count == 0)
            RigheRiempimenti.Add(new RigaRiempimento() { RiempimentoId = this.RiempimentoId, NumeroRiga = 0, });

        var riga = RigheRiempimenti.OrderBy(x => x.NumeroRiga).LastOrDefault();
        
        if (!riga.BolleEntrate.Contains(bolla))
            riga.BolleEntrate.Add(bolla);
    }


[Table("RigheRiempimenti")]
public class RigaRiempimento
{

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Riempimento")]
    public long RiempimentoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Riempimento Riempimento { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int NumeroRiga { get; set; }

    public long NumeroFrutti { get; set; }

    public float PesoFrutti { get; set; }

    public int PercentualeRiempimento { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BollaEntrata> BolleEntrate { get; set; }


    public RigaRiempimento()
    {
        BolleEntrate = new HashSet<BollaEntrata>();
    }
}
```

and my modelbuilder is defined like this

```
      modelBuilder.Entity<RigaRiempimento>()
            .HasMany(e => e.BolleEntrate)
            .WithMany(e => e.RigheRiempimenti)
            .Map(e =>
            {
                e.MapLeftKey("RiempimentoId", "NumeroRiga");
                e.MapRightKey("IdBolla");
                e.ToTable("RigheBolle");
            });
```

What does it mean the exception I recived??
The code works fine for a few minutes and after start to generate me this exception...